# How to resolve "400 Bad Request" after cloning a webserver that uses Cloudflare for SSL?

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, cloudflare, 400

I'm trying to clone a webserver that hosts sites that rely on Cloudflare for their SSL certificates.

After cloning the server and updating my local `hosts` file to point the site to the new server, I'm met with the error:

```
400 Bad Request
No required SSL certificate was sent
nginx
```

How can I work around this or resolve this without needing to take the original server/site offline?

If it matters, the website is a Wordpress site.

---

Note: I saw [this similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/501912/nginx-proxy-ssl-clr-400-bad-request-error) but it doesn't seem to quite cross over into the problem I'm seeing (Nginx used at proxy there, and no Cloudflare component)

Comment: The problem is in the configuration of your cloned server - which you don't provide. Likely you require in your config the client to provide a client certificate (`ssl_verify_client on`), which the client does not have.

Comment: Thank you so much - that was the answer! If you submit it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the configuration of your cloned server. Likely you require in your config the client to provide a client certificate (ssl_verify_client on), which the client does not have.